# ReactJS production url path setting

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I exec npm run build .

move folder name:build to apache server :8080

rename build's folder name to my_web_test

On local server is not working.

[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSgoL.png)

project setting:

package.json > `honepage : "http://localhost:8080/my_web_test/"`

.env.prodcution > `PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:8080/my_web_test/`

index.js

```
const main_router = '/my_web_test';

<ConnectedRouter history={createHistory()}>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={'/'} render={() => {
                    const user_id = sessionStorage.is_login;
                    if(is_login){
                        return <Dashboard/>
                    } else {
                        return <Redirect to={main_router+'/login'}/>
                    }
                }}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Redirect to={main_router+'/'}  />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
```

Comment: What is your problem ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I didn't show /login page on production environment.

Comment: I want browser url input "http://localhost:8080/my_web_test/" . Will  Redirect to component={Login}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With react router v4 you can set a basename property.

```
<ConnectedRouter basename={main_router} history={createHistory()}>
```

You will still need to make sure the server actually maps the request to the html file with your react application. This can be done with a .htaccess file for example.

Comment: `basename={main_router}`

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar you're right, I missed that and will edit my post. Thank you!

Comment: i try to add <ConnectedRouter basename={main_router} history={createHistory()}>, but the same problem. I trying add a .htaccess.

Comment: I found a guide on [here](https://stanko.github.io/react-router-subfolder-on-server/)